# Reflection usage for creating instance of a class into DLL

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following code:

```
var type = typeof(PluginInterface.iMBDDXPluginInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));

Type t = types.ElementAt(0);
PluginInterface.iMBDDXPluginInterface instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as PluginInterface.iMBDDXPluginInterface;
TabPage tp = new TabPage();

tp = instance.pluginTabPage();
```

The class within the dll implements the PluginInterface and the Type in the code above, is definately the correct class/type, however when I try to create an instance through the interface i get an error message saying:

> Object reference not assigned to an instance of an object.

Anybody know why?

Thanks.

Comment: On which line do you get this exception?

Comment: I get it when I call the instance.pluginTabPage method.

Comment: You need a better error message - change your `Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Plugin...` to `(Plugin...) Activator.CreateInstance(t)`

Comment: Fixed it now....it was an error with my dll class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage();
tp = instance.pluginTabPage();
```

makes no sense.

Do:

```
TabPage tp = instance.pluginTabPage();
```

---

Also do next:

```
Type type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .FirstOrDefault(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
if (type != null)
{
    // create instance
}
```

or (my preferred way):

```
from asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
from type in asm.GetTypes()
where !type.IsInterface && !type.IsAbstract && typeof(ITarget).IsAssignableFrom(type)
select (ITarget)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Have fixed the initial error - was an issue with my dll class.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the type in reflector. Maybe the constructor takes arguments that you are not correctly passing to `Activator.CreateInstance` .

Comment: That was my first thought too, but wouldn't a  `MissingMethodException` be thrown instead if this were the case? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx

Comment: The class has no parameters, it simply has a default constructor taking nothing?

Comment: Well, my point was that maybe it had more ctors and the one without args maybe forgets to set a crucial variable, thus causing the exception.